# Add new data series and series options in jqPlot

Tags: jqplot

I use jqPlot for creating a graph in my web application.
Initially, the graph is blank.

My goal is I allow users to select a specific dataset from a dropdown. Each dataset will have different maker render options derived from a lookup file that I maintain separately.

When users select a new dataset, that dataset will be drawn onto the graph with other previous selected datasets.  Is it possible to achieve this effort dynamically through jqPlot APIs?

Here is what I have done:

1. I add new dataset to `myChart.data`.  The `data` property is an an array of all datasets from the chart.
2. I clone a new series from `myChart.series[0]`, extend the cloned series with my specific marker render options and add the cloned series to `myChart.series`.
3. I redraw the chart.

Apparently it doesn't work.  I always get an error like at line 3059 jquery.jqplot.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shadowCanvas' of undefined
```

Looking thru the source code, I realize that the jqPlot init function also does initializations of other members of the graph and that is why I receive the above error.

Please help.

============================================
I solved the problem by accessing the data and the options from the jqplot directly (not thru any API). To draw the graph when new data series added, I will do:

jQuery.jqplot('ptGraph', chartData, chartOpts);

chartData will contain old and new series data and chartOpts will contain old and new data series options.  THe new options will have to contain customized parameters (like marker icons, etc). There is no API involved, just pure coding for now.